# Why $GLOBAL is not working in function scope - PHP

Tags: php, function, scope, global-variables, superglobals

I have write the code like same two times: on root of the file and in the function

$GLOBAL superglobal variable is not working in the function. But same thing already working in out of fuction

Reference: 
1. [php_superglobals](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp) 
2. [reserved.variables.globals](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

**Code:**

```
<?php

// working here
$GLOBALS['x'] = "Root of the file";
echo $x;

// same things are not working in the function.
function checkglobal() { 
    $GLOBALS['z'] = "In the function.";
    echo $z;
} 
checkglobal();
```

**Output:**

> Root of the file
>
> NOTICE Undefined variable: z on line number 10

**[Click and check here](https://3v4l.org/5TYMJ)**

Comment: What exactly do you think *`GLOBAL`* means…?

Comment: You'll be able to use it in the **global** scope (outside the function). https://3v4l.org/5TYMJ

Comment: @deceze $GLOBAL is a superglobasl variable . https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Comment: @RohitGoyani I think he knows that ;-) pretty sure. Yet, he would have (most likely) used http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php instead of W3Schools' reference.

Comment: Yes, and through it you can access variables in the *global* scope. Not in function scopes.

Comment: Global doesn't mean "everywhere", and it's only just dawned on me that that's actually quite confusing.

Comment: @deceze, yes right.

Comment: @Qirel, Thank you. but why not working in function.

Comment: Use the PHP manual, not w3schools. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php See example 1

Comment: `echo $GLOBALS['z'];` in function `echo $z;` outside of function after it has been defined in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake in my code.
$GLOBALS superglobal variable is used for creating global variable and access that in non-global scope.
Need to declare the global variable with "global" keyword, if we want to use directly in non-global scope.

**Corrected Code:**

```
<?php

// working here
$GLOBALS['x'] = "Root of the file";
echo $x;
 
// same things are not working in the function.
function checkglobal() { 
    $GLOBALS['z'] = "In the function.";
    global z; // declare global variable *******************
    echo $z;
} 
checkglobal();
```

**Output:**

> Root of the file
>
> In the function.

Answer (score 0):

This script will not produce any output because the echo statement refers to a local version of the $z variable, and it has not been assigned a value within this scope. You may notice that this is a little bit different from the C language in that global variables in C are automatically available to functions unless specifically overridden by a local definition. This can cause some problems in that people may inadvertently change a global variable. In PHP global variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going to be used in that function.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please suggest me, which things are missing in my code? how to work the code in the function also?